# Unable to display image from database when using nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-resources

**Problem displaying image from database**
I am working on a website which allows both **customers**   and **account users** to upload their pictures.

Using a recipe provided in the book **Agile Web Development with Rails**, I have managed to make it work for the **customers** module where I have two tables, **Customer** and **Image** on a 1 on 1 relationship. And I display the image with

```
<img src="<%= url_for(:action => 'picture', :id => @customer.id) %>" alt="Picture" class="photo"/>
```

which generates the following html example

```
<img src="/customers/picture/986" alt="Picture" class="photo">
```

Now, my second module is slightly more complicated where I have 3 tables involved.
1. **Account** - which only stores username and password
2. **Basic_profile** - which stores things like Name, Gender, birthday and etc. Note -  I'm using the *edit* page here to upload and display the user's picture.
3. **Picture** - which stores account users pictures.

The relationship here is **Picture** belongs_to **Basic_profile**, and **Basic_profile** belongs_to **Account**.

In my routes I have a nested resource.

```
  resources :accounts do
    resource :basic_profile, :contact
  end
```

Notice the singular **basic_profile** which makes the path as

> **//localhost:3000/accounts/1/basic_profile/edit**

Uploading and saving into the database are all fine. My problem now is displaying the picture in the edit page. The following code doesn't work.

```
<img src="<%= url_for(:action => 'picture', :id => @basic_profile.id) %>" alt="Picture" class="profile_picture" />
```

I have tried to fix this but nothing works. Senselessly playing with the path like

> **//localhost:3000/accounts/1/basic_profile/picture**

gives me routing error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The solution was simple. Add **"get :picture"** within the nested route.

```
  resources :accounts do
    resource :basic_profile do
      get :picture
    end
  end
```